# using the same paypal IPN for 2 different sites.

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Here's a critical problem I'm facing: I've got a few sites which need payments to be accessed, but the problem is that for each of them the IPN needs to be set.

E.g., lets take 2 domains:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
```

Now, in order to buy a subscription in `domain1` I need to have the IPN directed to `domain1.com/payments.php`

and as for `domain2`, to buy a subscription I need to set the IPN to `domain2.com/payments.php`, but I can't keep both the domains for the same IPN

Is there any way to get around this issue?

Or do I need to create another site to act as the payment processor for all my domains and redirect them to it?

help is appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NotifyURL parameter to set an IPN URL for individual payments.  This will override anything in the PayPal profile.

It sounds like you're working with subscription buttons, so the parameter name is "notify_url" in that case.  Just include notify_url and set it to the URL of the IPN you'd like to use for that particular button and it will do what you're after.